# Selecting constructor with fewer parameters in Unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a 3rd party class library. One of the classes in that library, has a constructor with multiple overrides.

I want to tell Unity to create the class, using a constructor with fewer parameters (by default, it selects the one with the most number of parameters). How can I do this?

I know I can use `InjectionFactory`, but I prefer to let Unity create the object for me, than writing a delegate for it. Also if I had access to the source I could probably label the desired constructor with `InjectionConstructor`, but I don't. So what would be my other option?

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot use `InjectionConstructorAttribute` (as you mentioned, the library is not yours), you can use the [InjectionConstructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.injectionconstructor%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx) class (not an attribute). You will need to call `Resolve` yourself to make sure `Unity` builds up the constructor parameters. Something like this:

```
IUnityContainer c = new UnityContainer()
    .RegisterType<IStuff, GoodStuff>()
    .RegisterType<StuffUser>(new InjectionConstructor(c.Resolve<IStuff>()));
```

Comment: +1: InjectionConstructor is the way to go. Just be aware that with `c.Resolve<IStuff>()` the same instance will be injected for every `StuffUser`.  If you wanted the container to resolve a new `IStuff` for every `StuffUser` you could use `container.RegisterType<StuffUser>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IStuff>()));`